# Subpages or single page

Tags: navigation, structure

What are pros and cons of using **single page** with anchors vs **section with subpages** in menu?
I'm asking in context of "About us" section where we have such information as: basic facts, offices, team and values.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about your content and goals.

**Subpages**
Nice to use when you want to give the full answer about your company/brand, when you are building a whole storyline as Silenza does.

[Silenza](http://silenza.it/)

---

**Anchors**
On other hand, anchors are better to use when you want to give information which will be "scanned" at one glance. You can also use embedded forms to grasp feedback quickly (as Invision does). Also, you have another great plus to use different interactive techniques such as parallax, parallax with a twist etc.

*Examples:*

[Huge Inc](http://www.hugeinc.com/about)

[Flawless](https://flawlessapp.io/team)

[Invision](http://www.invisionapp.com/customers)

Comment: Thanks @Ryna. I've found some answers in duplicated question as well.